# Updating TextBox/NumericUpDowns/Labels/Progress Bars from another thread

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous, extension-methods, invoke

We currently have an application that reads data from serial communications. Throughout the application we need to display this data in the UI, and so we have created a method to update the textbox/label/numeric/progress bar using BeginInvoke.

However, this is starting to become cumbersome, as every control needs its own 'Setter', such that we already have 20 or so methods, which all do basically the same thing.

While I can see an easy way to genericize this to a specific control (e.g. only 1 for labels, 1 for textboxes), it would be ideal to only have 1 (maybe extension) method that we can call to update the data in the UI.

Here was our original method splayed everywhere:

```
private void SetCell1Cell2Async(decimal value)
    {
        if (spinCell1Cell2.InvokeRequired)
        {
            spinCell1Cell2.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate
            {
                spinCell1Cell2.Value = value;
            }));
        }
        else
        {
            if (spinCell1Cell2.IsDisposed) return; // Do not process if the control has been disposed of
            if (spinCell1Cell2.IsHandleCreated)
            {
                // This handle may not be created when creating this form AFTER data is already flowing
                // We could capture this data for future display (i.e. via deferUpdate = true or similar), but it is easier to ignore it
                // i.e. Do Nothing
                return;
            }
            spinCell1Cell2.Value = value;
        }
    }
```

Here is our current method (this works for Controls that use the `Text` property to display data):

```
delegate void SetTextAsyncCallback(Control ctrl, string text);
public static void SetTextAsync(this Control invoker, string text)
{
    if (invoker.InvokeRequired)
    {
        invoker.BeginInvoke(new SetTextAsyncCallback(SetTextAsync), invoker, text);
    }
    else
    {
        if (invoker.IsDisposed) return; // Do not process if the control has been disposed of
        if (!invoker.IsHandleCreated)
        {
            // This handle may not be created when creating this form AFTER data is already flowing
            // We could capture this data for future display (i.e. via deferUpdate = true or similar), but it is easier to ignore it
            // i.e. Do Nothing
            return;
        } 
        invoker.Text = text;
    }
}
```

As you may see, this method works with anything that uses the `Text` property to display its data.

Ideally I would like to be able to 'pass in' the property to update, and to supply a method that would take a `string`, `double`, `decimal`, `boolean` etc, but I'm a bit lost as where to go from here.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a more universal solution, with something like this in the Form:

```
delegate void ActionCallback();

private void SetText()
{
    this.SafeInvoke(() =>
        {
            if (spinCell1Cell2.IsDisposed) return;
            if (!spinCell1Cell2.IsHandleCreated) return;
            // Do stuff
        });
}

private void SafeInvoke(ActionCallback action)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
}
```

Using delegates, you only have to declare the actual action once, while the type of execution is decided later on (in the SafeInvoke-method). If you'd rather have some extension methods, here is an example:

```
public delegate void ActionCallback();

public static void SafeInvoke(this Form form, ActionCallback action)
{
    if (form.InvokeRequired)
        form.Invoke(action);
    else
        action();
}

public static void SafeSetText(this Control ctl)
{
    var form = ctl.FindForm();
    if (form == null) return; // or do something else

    form.SafeInvoke(() =>
        {
            // Do stuff
        });
}
```

**Edit**
After reading your question again I noticed this wasn't really what you asked about, so I'll give you a more relevant example:

```
public static void SafeUpdate<T>(this T ctl, ActionCallback action) where T : Control
{
    var form = ctl.FindForm();
    if (form == null) return; // or do something else

    SafeInvoke(action);
}

// Then in some other method
{
    textBox1.SafeUpdate(() =>
    {
        textBox1.Text = "123";
        textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    });
}
```